Aligning two rasters using rasterio.reproject

I collected a set of images using a drone. After that, I created a set of orthomosaic images. Next, I took two images that were acquired for the same location and at different times of the year. I am trying to align them using the rasterio.reproject algorithm, but I see some error in the results for the resulting images. Please suggest other algorithms to minimize the error.

What system was used to collect the images? Satellite? Airplane? Drone? Aerial and drone imagery can be notoriously hard to align perfectly given how wind can constantly shift the exact positioning of planes and drones.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I collected a set of images using a drone. After that, I created an orthomosaic image.

Now I have a set of orthomosaic images and I want to align them.

You will probably be better off using recognizable geometries across the two images as ground control points to rectify the two images. This is doable using GIS, for example the  georeferencer tool in QGIS https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html
